# The method add(T) in the type List<T> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I searched stack overflow for this error, but none quite had the same design as I have. Suggestions for terminology to aid in finding a similar topic like the sample code below would be appreciated.

Here is a simple test case that demonstrates the error:

```
import java.util.List;

public class SimpleTest {

    abstract class AbsTask<T>
    {

    }

    abstract class AbsQueue<T extends AbsTask<?>>
    {
        private List<T> lst;

        public void addSpecialItem()
        {
            lst.add(new SpecialItem()); // Error occurs here
        }



    }

    class SpecialItem extends AbsTask<Void>
    {

    }

}
```

I am trying to add a method to my abstract class `AbsQueue` called `addSpecialItem`, which will insert the SpecialItem class into the list generic list T which is essentially a list of `AbsTask`.

Here is the error: `The method add(T) in the type List<T> is not applicable for the arguments (SimpleTest.SpecialItem)`

I can resolve this error if I type case the add line as follows:

```
lst.add((T)new SpecialItem());
```

Is there a way of handling this without type casting `new SpecialItem()` to `T`?

Answer (score 2):

Your abstract class must be instantiated to define what T is. Try this:

```
public class SimpleTest {

  static abstract class AbsTask<T> { }

  static class AbsQueue<T extends AbsTask<?>> {
    private List<T> lst;

    public void addSpecialItem(T item) {
      lst.add(item); 
    }
  }

  static class Test {

    public void main() {
      AbsQueue<SpecialItem> queue = new AbsQueue<SpecialItem>();
      queue.addSpecialItem(new SpecialItem());
    }
  }

  static class SpecialItem extends AbsTask<String> {

  }

}
```

Comment: The main objective was to have it add the special item from within the AbsQueue. The purpose of this is to hide some functionality from the programmer that inherits AbsQueue, which in this case is to add the special item as a signal for the queue. The test case presented is just a small example of what I am trying to do, unfortunately I cannot post the full example.

Comment: Yes but nothing prevents the programmer from creating an AbsQueue which is not of type `SpecialItem` but still extends `AbsTask`. That's why you can't just work with type `SpecialItem` within your abstract class, you have to work with `T`.

Comment: Type casting it will work, it just will throw a type safety warning. I do not get a runtime error when compiling and running when I typecast SpecialItem to T when adding it to the List<T>

Comment: If you have to type case you're doing something wrong. Again, your AbsQueue is saying it works with type `T` which could be **any** class that inherits from `AbsTask`. Once your `AbsTask` is instantiated, the contract is that it is of type `T`. Avoid creating an API that lies, it's confusing and hard to debug.

Comment: Think of it as a flag for the queue. When the user gets an item from the queue, it is being passed to an abstract function. But before it passes the task to the abstract function, it does a check to see if the task it received is a termination task. If it is then the queue is terminated and the task is not passed to the abstract function.  I appologize if my test case does not show this, I should have added some more functionality to AbsQueue to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

A `List<T>` is *supposed* to be a list that can only include elements of type `T`, but the code you've written doesn't ensure that `SpecialItem` is a subtype of `T`.

It's not clear what you actually want, but I *think* what you want is a `List<AbsTask<?>>`, not a `List<T>` for some *specific* `T` that extends `AbsTask<?>`.

Comment: The main idea is I want to add a special task into the list from the abstract queue. I want this to be done internally so that the programmer extending the abstract queue does not have to do this. I think my only option is to just bite the bullet and type case and add the suppress warnings.

Comment: The compiler is telling you that this cast is fundamentally broken (which it is).  A `List<T>` should not contain anything other than Ts.

Comment: Typecasting it to T is safe because SpecialItem is a child of AbsTask<Void>, which satisfies T in AbsQueue, which is of type T extends AbsTask<?>. The compiler will just give me a warning. `Type safety: Unchecked cast from SignalTerminationTask to T` But I am safe because I know that SpecialItem meets the type requirements.

Comment: @JamesHobbs: No, that's false.  When you say `T extends AbsTask<?>`, that means that there's some _specific T being chosen_ that extends `AbsTask<?>`.  `T` could be some other subtype of `AbsTask<?>` that has no relationship to `SpecialItem`.  This is why I think what you actually want is to get rid of `T` and just have a `List<AbsTask<?>>`, which is _actually_ a `List` of objects that can be of any subtype of `AbsTask<?>`, and can be of different subtypes.

Comment: I cannot use List<AbsTask<?>> because it will not define a specific type, I need to pass the type T back to the user of the AbsQueue. Also, type casting it does work. It just throws a warning, but no errors are thrown.

Comment: If your caller iterates through the List<T> later and treats its elements as Ts, that code will fail with a ClassCastException. Your code looks like it works, but it's really concealing a time bomb.  The warning is there for a reason.

Comment: I wish I could post the full example, and I was hoping to just create a simple case that shows the error, but I will try to explain without getting deep into it.

The caller isn't iterating through the Queue, but rather is handed Tasks from the queue. This is done inside the AbsQueue, which calls a handoff function with the T task as a parameter. I have a flag that signifies if a task is a terminator or not. So before handing it off I check if it is being terminated. If it is then that task is not passed to the caller. I hope this clarifies a little...

Answer (score 0):

At that line of code `lst.add(new SpecialItem());` the compiler does not yet know what `T` is.